# poetry Virtual environment already activated

Tags: python, python-poetry

Running the following

```
poetry shell
```

returns the following error

```
/home/harshagoli/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.                                                                                                                                                                                    
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)                                                                                                                                                    
The currently activated Python version 2.7.17 is not supported by the project (^3.7).                                                                                                         
Trying to find and use a compatible version.                                                                                                                                                  
Using python3 (3.7.5)                                                                                                                                                                         
Virtual environment already activated: /home/harshagoli/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-project-0wt3KWFj-py3.7
```

How can I get past this error? Why doesn't this command work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`poetry shell` is a really buggy command, and this is often talked about among the maintainers. A workaround for this specific issue is to activate the shell manually. It might be worth aliasing the following

```
source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
```

so you need to paste this into your `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc`

```
alias acpoet="source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate"
```

Now you can run `acpoet` to activate your poetry env (don't forget to source your file to enable the command)

Comment: This does not work at all, see mr.bjerre answer for something more reliable

Comment: You can set this up as alias in your profile as - `alias activate_poetry="source \"\$(poetry env list --full-path | grep Activated | cut -d' ' -f1 )/bin/activate\""`. Make sure you are in the project directory (dir with pyproject.toml) when you run this.

Comment: You should substitute double quotes in the originally proposed alias by single quotes, otherwise that alias is executed immediately when `.bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` is loaded.

Answer (score 48):

I'd have to do the following

```sh
source "$( poetry env list --full-path | grep Activated | cut -d' ' -f1 )/bin/activate"
```

Comment: You can set this up as alias in your profile as - `alias activate_poetry="source \"\$(poetry env list --full-path | grep Activated | cut -d' ' -f1 )/bin/activate\""`. Make sure you are in the project directory (dir with pyproject.toml) when you run this.

Answer (score 7):

It's similar to activating a normal virtual environment. But we need to find out path of the poetry virtual env.

We can find the path via `poetry env info --path`

```
source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
```

Explained in [this poetry demo](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#activating-the-virtual-environment).

Answer (score 0):

Simply kill existing terminal, open a new one, and `poetry shell` voila

Answer (score -2):

If you've installed poetry using the traditional pip command, poetry will be limited to create virtual environments for the python version for which it has been installed.

Try uninstalling poetry using:

`pip3 uninstall poetry`

Then reinstall using:

`brew install poetry` if you have a Mac.

This worked for me.